# Backing up configs from a multi context firewall to Ciscoworks LMS Prime

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

We have Ciscoworks AKA Cisco Prime LMS version 4.2.2. We also have some multi context firewalls. Is LMS capable of going into the admin context of the firewall and backing up all of the configs from the other contexts?

Or more simply, whats the solution to backup the config of the system context of a multi context firewall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to back up each context individually by configuring it as it's own "device" in CiscoWorks.

It has been requested to add capabilities to backup from the admin context, but it isn't available at this time.

See this [bug/enhancement request](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/BugToolKit/search/getBugDetails.do?method=fetchBugDetails&bugId=CSCsl65838) (CCO login required).

Answer (score 0):

The tool of choice for this task would be Cisco Security Manager.
For multi-vendor enviroment i would recommend HP Network Automation.